# Using Trim in multiple where clause of linq with Join clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq

One of the columns of my table has spacing in them. I'm trying to query it using linq, but I get an error. The code is:

```
(from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2
on t1.t2_Id equals t2.Id
where t1.status == "Active"
where t2.column_value.Trim() == parameter
select t1).ToList();
```

The error is:

> Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid
>   property or method.

How do I trim the column?

Comment: Which type of LINQ is this? To entities?

Comment: The error message is commonly associated with the CRM Linq provider.  Are you using that?

Comment: Per a comment below, this is using a CRM Linq provider, possibly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681573(v=MSDN.10).aspx

Comment: yeah, its CRM linq provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `.Trim()` cannot be executed server-side.  You can see this from the error

> Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.

And that `Trim()` is the only property or method invoked.  I understand that SQL Server should be able to process Trim(), but not every provider can (*UPDATE: It is confirmed that the provider is the CRM Linq Provider*).

You can use

```
(from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2
on t1.t2_Id equals t2.Id
where t1.status == "Active"    
select t1).AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.column_value.Trim() == parameter)
.ToList();
```

AsEnumerable() causes the rest of the Linq expression to be executed client side rather than in the database.  One issue with this approach is that you will quite possibly retrieve more records from the database than you end up using, since some filtering is client side.

Comment: Multiple `where` are certainly allowed.

Comment: Thank you Eric, but I cannot access column_value which belongs to t2 from here.

Comment: +1, because having multiple where clause in *even* LINQ to object doesn't error out as my initial guess.

Comment: @MikeStrobel: I bet he's using the CRM Linq Provider.  Try googling his error message "An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method."

Comment: @EricJ Indeed, I just saw your comment and [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/pabloperalta/notsupportedexception-invalid-where-condition-an-entity-member-is-invoking-an-invalid-property-or-method) suggests you were right after all.

Comment: @Payal: You `select t1`, so you are only returning `t1` from your query.  You can use a projection to return properties from both objects, or even both objects in their entirety e.g. `select new { Status = t1.status, ColumnValue = t1.column_value, SomethingElse = t2.somethingElseYouNeed }`.

Comment: Habib, even I use && instead of 2nd where statement, i get the same above error: Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.

Comment: @Payal Try rewriting your statement the way I suggest above.  && will not solve the problem.

Comment: Eric, i only select t1, because i am using it as an entity to bind to my datacontract. I need the entire t1 enitity. If I select multiple entities, then i need to separate it out for binding, as I don't need the other entities. Is there no simpler way to trim this column?

Comment: Mike, this is CRM entity.

Comment: Thank you Eric, I was able to make the call as you suggested above. I added anonymous type to include t2 column_value and the use where clause to trim it. I separate it out after the linq call.

Comment: Eric, i have a related issue to this now, even though I can separate out the entity from the anonymous type, its references are null, so i cannot get values from the reference tables as I use to before. Can you please help?

Comment: Please create a new question for this new issue.  If you post a link to the new question here, I'm glad to have a look.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do like this. To join conditions either you need to use `&&` or `||` based on your requirement.

```
from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2
on t1.t2_Id equals t2.Id
where t1.status == "Active"
&& t1.column_value.Trim() == parameter
select t1).ToList();
```

Comment: Can Trim() execute server-side?

Comment: @EricJ., It will be converted to `RTRIM(LTRIM(` call in Entity framework with SQL Server

Comment: @Habib: This is not stated to be SQL Server, and the error indicates that the provider cannot process *some* property or method in the expression.

Comment: @EricJ., I missed the error exact text in the question. I must admit, this is probably the first time I have seen `Trim` failing.

Comment: @EricJ. in those cases the error is usually NotSupportedException : EF can't recognize x...

Comment: @All, so far i have tried this, and it is working, so i have posted this. Let me know, where this can be problem! That will be helpful for me!

Comment: In LINQ two `where` clauses are effectively the same as a `&&` operator. This answer is meaningless wrt the problem.

Comment: They're only the same if the query provider rewrites the chained `Where` operator as an `AndAlso`.  Some third-party providers may not be so aggressive.

Comment: Well, it's a shot in the dark at best.

Comment: @Selman22: His provider is probably CRM Linq Provider (based on googling the actual error message).